# rails devise: user and account system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've been trying to add an account to a user for a couple of days now.

I've installed Devise with no problems, but now I wanted to add a **Company Name** field to my registration form.

Here's my code:

## app/models/account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name
   has_many :users
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

## app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :account

   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

   attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :account_attributes, :account, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

end
```

## app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
   <%= devise_error_messages! %>

   <div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :first_name %></div>

   <div><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :last_name %></div>

   <%= f.fields_for :account do |account_form| %>
      <div><%= account_form.label :name %><br />
  <%= account_form.text_field :name %></div>
   <% end %>

   <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
   <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

   <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
   <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

   <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

   <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

This is all the code I have. I haven't changed anything more.

And this is the error I got:

```
Account(#2175324980) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#2169631580)
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I've found the solution:

I've changed

```
<%= f.fields_for :account do |account_form| %>
```

To

```
<%= f.fields_for :account_attributes, resource.account do |account_form| %>
```

Now I'm trying to add a :plan to account_form and I'm getting:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: plan
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok, rookie mistake. I've just added :plan to account model.

After that I was getting an query error, I just changed some fields in my DB from null => false to null => true and voila.

Comment: I believe your `user` should be accepting nested attributes for account, not the other way around, otherwise you would be creating an account with fields_for user

Comment: When I remove the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users` from my account model it removes the text field from the form.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to look something like this. This involves subclassing devise's registrations controller

```
#models
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name
   has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :account
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
   attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :account_attributes, :account, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

end

#app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   def new
      @account = Account.new
      super
   end
end


#routes
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}


#view
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
   <%= devise_error_messages! %>

   <div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :first_name %></div>

   <div><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :last_name %></div>

   <%= f.fields_for @account do |account_form| %>
      <div><%= account_form.label :name %><br />
  <%= account_form.text_field :name %></div>
   <% end %>

   <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
   <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

   <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
   <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

   <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

   <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have now, but the `fields_for` is not working, since I can't see the account label and input.

Comment: Try making a new Account object in the controller action and doing `fields_for @account` instead.

Comment: Users or accounts controller? Since the users controller are handled by devise and I don't actually have an accounts controller. Like I said in the original post that's the only code I've done for this.

Comment: I updated my answer to include subclassing devise's registrations controller so you can set @account during the new action.

Comment: The label and input are already showing, but I keep getting the same error: `Account(#2237699320) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#2232765200)`